# reduce the time complexity of nested for loop

Tags: javascript

Basically I am trying to bring down the time complexity of a series of functions that I have

```
const companies = [
    {
     staff: [
      {
        id: 1,
        qualities: [
          {
            id: 2,
            tags: [
              'efficient',
              'hard-working'
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So I have an `array` of `companies` and within that is another `array` of `staff` and then again within that there is an `array` of `qualities` and finally an `array` of `tags`

now I have a predetermined list of tags that I need to match users to for each company like so

```
companies: [
 xyz: [
   {
    tag: 'smart',
    users: []
   }
 ],
 // ...
];
```

so basically I need to loop through each pre-determined tag, then loop through each company, then loop through each user and loop through each tag to create this view

so basically something like this

```
const tags = [
  'smart',
  'hard-working',
  'efficient'
];

getUserTags(tagName) {
  const users = [];
  companies.forEach(company => {
    company.users.forEach(user => {
      user.tags.forEach(tag => {
        if (tag === tagName) {
          users.push(user);
        }
      });
    });  
  });
  return users; 
}
```

as you can see this is super inefficent and the big O works out to be O(n^4) which is horrible.

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you only want to *count* them, don't put them in an array but just increment an integer.

Comment: Are you genuinely trying to make the code faster, or just simpler to read/maintain? They're often not the same thing. If the former, how slow is it right now in the worst case?

Comment: No, if that's the structure your data has, there's no way to avoid completely traversing it. You cannot get time complexity down, other than by choosing a more suitable data structure as input.

Comment: @Bergi unfortunately I do need them stored in array - because I do further mutations

Comment: @Bergi okay that makes sense, I just wanted to make sure that there wasnt an obvious way to make this perform better

Comment: @jarmod I would like this function to perform better, because as it is it slows down the page considerably

Comment: "*for each tag it would have to loop*" - ah, wait, that's the part of the code you haven't shown. No, you would not need to do that. Instead of calling `getCountOfTags` multiple times, loop only once through the users and their tags, and collect them in a count-by-tagname map data structure.

Comment: @Bergi sorry I will update my question to be more specific there are a few things going on here

Comment: Oh, also while writing the code for my answers I noticed that you even have a third level of looping/nesting, as each user seems to have multiple qualities.

Comment: Minor: the original `companies` object appears to have incorrect structure.

Comment: You should consider changing to an Object structure that requires less iteration.

Comment: @StackSlave unfortunately this comes from a backend data structure I can't change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there could be 50 tags […] so for each tag it would have to [call the `getUserTags` function and] loop through every user and then loop through each users tags to see if its a match to get the total count.

No, that you shouldn't do. Instead, loop only once through the users and the tags of each user, and collect them in a array-by-tagname map data structure. Use something like

```
getUsersByTags(companies, tags) {
  let map = new Map();
  for (const tag of tags) {
    map.set(tag, []);
  }
  for (const company of companies) {
    for (const user of company.staff) {
      for (const quality of user.qualities) {
        for (const tag of quality.tags) {
          const n = tag.name;
          if (map.has(n))
            map.get(n).push(user);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return map;
}
```

You cannot avoid traversing the whole company-staff-quality-tag structure to access all your tag data. Just make sure to not do it more than once.

Comment: @SmokeyDawson Thanks, renaming `users` to `companies` doesn't really change my answer though. The structure in your second snippet (`companies: […`) isn't syntactically valid, I'm not sure what to do with that? Also in your edit you removed the fact that you're counting tags, and replaced it with only generic `// do stuff`. Without knowing what the result is, we cannot advise any better algorithm.

Comment: OK, updated, but the gist of the answer doesn't change.

Comment: No return value.

Answer (score -1):

As far as time complexity goes, you say you want 4 layers of abstraction.  (Before the edit to your question it was 3 was users, qualities, tags).  Now we have Companies, Staff, Qualities, Tags.  With this structure you should be expecting  O(n^4).  The below code does not try to change the level of complexity, but it might be quicker due to only keeping a count rather than items and using includes to short circuit the exit from a loop.

This can be done using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```
let getCountOfTags = (users, tagName) => users.reduce(
    (acc, item) => acc + item.qualities.reduce(
        (qAcc, q) => qAcc + (q.tags.includes(tagName) ? 1 : 0),
        0
    ), 
    0
);
```

We use `reduce` to get a single value from the accumulation of an array by summing the tag values being identified as being included in each quality item.

Comment: Wow, instant downvote seconds after posting.  Not even enough time to read my answer.  Would the downvoter care to give a reason why?

Comment: Thanks, yes, actually map isn't needed.  We can also just use `includes` because a single tag wouldn't make sense to appear more than once in the list of quality tags.

Comment: It's unclear why this solution reduces the time complexity?